# Force fullcalendar to render even in hidden tab

Tags: fullcalendar

fullcalendar is smart enough to only render if its on a visible div.
Is there any way to force the renderization even in a hidden div?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `visibility: hidden`

http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/567/

```
<div id='calendar' style='visibility:hidden'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken but this is not possible, to my knowledge.
However, a workaround for this is to call the render function when the tab is shown.
Assuming you are using Bootstrap (4):

```
$('a[href="#tab_id"]').on('shown.bs.tab',function(){
  calendar.render();
});
```